# In TypeScript, why is my type aliasing returning errors?

Tags: typescript

In Car.ts, I have the following code:

```
export class Car {

    static SMALL: string = "small";
    static MEDIUM: string = "medium";
    static LARGE: string = "large";

}
```

In CarSize.ts, I have the following code:

```
import { Car } from "./Car";

type CARSIZE = Car.SMALL | Car.MEDIUM | Car.LARGE;
```

I'm trying to create a CARSIZE type which can only be one of `Car.SMALL`, `Car.MEDIUM` or `CAR.LARGE`.

I receive the following error:

> 'Car' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: use enum instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Car.SMALL` is a value, not a type.

I'd use string enum in this case:

```
enum CarSize {
  small = "small",
  medium = "medium",
  large = "large"
}
```

But if you really want to get this working, you can use `typeof` to get the type of the value. Also you'll need to define properties as `readonly` and remove explicit type notation, so compiler will be able to infer the types as literals:

```
class Car {
    static readonly SMALL = "small";
    static readonly MEDIUM = "medium";
    static readonly LARGE = "large";
}

type CARSIZE = typeof Car.SMALL | typeof Car.MEDIUM | typeof Car.LARGE;
```